# Getting a random variable with a Boltzmann distribution

Tags: distributions, density-function

How to get a random variable with a Boltzmann distribution as the probability density distribution?

Or more practically: In my Java program, I can easily produce a uniform random variable U(0,1) or a uniform distributed integer from the integer value range.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double dvar = rnd.nextDouble(); // U(0,1) [0..1)
int ivar = rnd.nextInt(); // [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]
```

Starting from this, how can I produce random variables with a Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: If you mean the *Maxwell-Boltmann* distribution, then the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) provides a simple method where it points out its square is the sum of three iid standard Normal variates: so just generate three such variates (using, say, the Box-Muller method) and compute the root of the sum of their squares. If you mean something more general than this (Boltzmann distributions [run a wide gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution)) then please include the particulars in your question.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should be able to get my desired random variable with this.